# Caret error: "all the Accuracy metric values are missing"

Tags: r, r-caret

I'm getting the following error and I don't know what may have gone wrong. 
I'm using R Studio with the 3.1.3 version of R for Windows 8.1 and using the Caret package for datamining.

I have the following training data:

`str(training)`

```
'data.frame':   212300 obs. of  21 variables:

 $ FL_DATE_MDD_MMDD     : int  101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 ...

 $ FL_DATE              : int  1012013 1012013 1012013 1012013 1012013 1012013 1012013 1012013 1012013 1012013 ...

 $ UNIQUE_CARRIER       : Factor w/ 13 levels "9E","AA","AS",..: 11 10 2 5 8 9 11 10 10 10 ...

 $ DEST                 : Factor w/ 150 levels "ABE","ABQ","ALB",..: 111 70 82 8 8 31 110 44 53 80 ...

 $ DEST_CITY_NAME       : Factor w/ 148 levels "Akron, OH","Albany, NY",..: 107 61 96 9 9 29 106 36 97 78 ...

 $ ROUNDED_TIME         : int  451 451 551 551 551 551 551 551 551 551 ...

 $ CRS_DEP_TIME         : int  500 520 600 600 600 600 600 600 602 607 ...

 $ DEP_DEL15            : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 ...

 $ CRS_ARR_TIME         : int  746 813 905 903 855 815 901 744 901 841 ...

 $ Conditions           : Factor w/ 28 levels "Blowing Snow",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...

 $ Dew.PointC           : num  -14.4 -14.4 -14.4 -14.4 -14.4 -14.4 -14.4 -14.4 -14.4 -14.4 ...

 $ Events               : Factor w/ 10 levels "","Fog","Fog-Rain",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

 $ Gust.SpeedKm.h       : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...

 $ Humidity             : int  68 68 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 71 ...

 $ Precipitationmm      : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...

 $ Sea.Level.PressurehPa: num  1021 1021 1022 1022 1022 ...

 $ TemperatureC         : num  -9.4 -9.4 -10 -10 -10 -10 -10 -10 -10 -10 ...

 $ VisibilityKm         : num  16.1 16.1 16.1 16.1 16.1 16.1 16.1 16.1 16.1 16.1 ...

 $ Wind.Direction       : Factor w/ 18 levels "Calm","East",..: 9 9 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 ...

 $ WindDirDegrees       : int  320 320 330 330 330 330 330 330 330 330 ...

 $ Wind.SpeedKm.h       : num  20.4 20.4 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 ...

 - attr(*, "na.action")=Class 'omit'  Named int [1:22539] 3 32 45 87 94 325 472 548 949 1333 ...

  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:22539] "3" "32" "45" "87" ...
```

and when I execute the following command:

```
ldaModel <- train(DEP_DEL15~.,data=training,method="lda",preProc=c("center","scale"),na.remove=TRUE)
```

I get:

> Something is wrong; all the Accuracy metric values are missing:
>   Accuracy       Kappa
>    Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA
>    1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA
>    Median : NA   Median : NA
>    Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN
>    3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA
>    Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA
>    NA's   :1     NA's   :1
>   Error in train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) : Stopping

Answer (score 7):

It is probably due to having about outcome factor with levels "0" and "1".

There is a specific warning issued when this happens: `At least one of the class levels are not valid R variables names; This may cause errors if class probabilities are generated because the variables names will be converted to: X0, X1"`

It seems that people uniformly ignore warnings so I'm going to make this throw an error in the next version.

Answer (score 0):

If the variables `Gust.SpeedKm.h` and `Precipitationmm` contain only `NA's` try  omitting those variables from your data before running the model. If they contain partial `NA's` and you think they could have predictive value as features then use imputation. Follow this documentation for [pre-processing in caret](http://www.inside-r.org/node/86978), including imputation.

Comment: I removed Gust.SpeedKm.h and Precipitationmm but when I tried to again I got similar results, however when I looked at the warnings, all were of the form: 15: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : model fit failed for Resample15: parameter=none Error : cannot allocate vector of size 604.2 Mb I have 26 similar warnings, My dataset hast 200000 rows and at least 20 columns. What can I do?