# caret - random-forests not working: "Something is wrong; all the Accuracy metric values are missing:"

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret

#### Related to these:

1. [getting this error in Caret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30475723/getting-this-error-in-caret)
2. https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/160

I'm getting this error:

```
Something is wrong; all the Accuracy metric values are missing:
    Accuracy       Kappa    
 Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA  
 1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA  
 Median : NA   Median : NA  
 Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN  
 3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA  
 Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA  
 NA's   :5     NA's   :5    
Error in train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) : Stopping
In addition: Warning message:
In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo,  :
  There were missing values in resampled performance measures.
```

The first link suggests that the levels of the response variable cannot be `0` and `1`. This is not the case in my data:

```
R> str(test$y)
 Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
R> levels(test$y)
[1] "No"  "Yes"
```

So, I'm not sure what's going on.

#### Ex. Data

```
test <- structure(list(y = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), x1 = structure(c(6L, 
40L, 26L, 7L, 18L, 9L, 26L, 36L, 23L, 16L, 6L, 20L, 23L, 26L, 
41L, 20L, 31L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 18L, 2L, 12L, 9L, 40L, 40L, 14L, 8L, 
2L, 20L, 15L, 12L, 8L, 17L, 17L, 21L, 18L, 32L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Accommodation and Restaurant Services", 
"Admin/Support Services", "Agriculture", "Arts, Entertainment, and Rec.", 
"Construction: Heavy and Civil Engineering", "Construction: of Buildings", 
"Construction: Specialty Trade Contractors", "EDU Services", 
"Finance / Insurance", "Fishing, Hunting, Trapping", "Forestry & Logging", 
"Health Care and Social Assistance", "Information", "Management of Companies and Enterprises", 
"Manufacturing: Food/Bev/Textile", "Manufacturing: Metals/Machinery/Computers/Appliances", 
"Manufacturing: Wood/Paper/Chemical/Mineral", "Merchandise Trade", 
"Mining, Quarrying, and Oil and Gas Extraction", "Other Services (Blue Collar)", 
"Prof./Sci./Tech: Acct / Tax", "Prof./Sci./Tech: Advertising / Media", 
"Prof./Sci./Tech: Architecture / Eng.", "Prof./Sci./Tech: Computer Design", 
"Prof./Sci./Tech: Law", "Prof./Sci./Tech: Mgmt Consulting", "Prof./Sci./Tech: Other", 
"Prof./Sci./Tech: R&D", "Prof./Sci./Tech: Specialized Design", 
"Public Admin.", "Real Estate", "Retail Trade", "Support Agriculture", 
"Transportation", "Unknown", "Utilities", "Warehousing", "Waste Management & Remediation Services", 
"Wholesale Trade: Brokers", "Wholesale Trade: Durable Goods", 
"Wholesale Trade: NonDurable Goods"), class = "factor"), x2 = structure(c(36L, 
11L, 35L, 46L, 5L, 10L, 37L, 41L, 11L, 5L, 5L, 10L, 20L, 10L, 
5L, 5L, 45L, 20L, 11L, 10L, 18L, 35L, 5L, 6L, 41L, 5L, 44L, 36L, 
39L, 10L, 44L, 8L, 34L, 15L, 39L, 10L, 18L, 19L, 35L, 11L), .Label = c("AK", 
"AL", "AR", "AZ", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DC", "DE", "FL", "GA", "HI", 
"IA", "ID", "IL", "IN", "KS", "KY", "LA", "MA", "MD", "ME", "MI", 
"MN", "MO", "MS", "MT", "NC", "ND", "NE", "NH", "NJ", "NM", "NV", 
"NY", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC", "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT", 
"VA", "VT", "WA", "WI", "WV", "WY"), class = "factor"), x3 = c(0.004714, 
0, 0.015551, 0.360246999999988, 5e-04, 0.035714, 0.357143, 0.00591043019290109, 
0.138889, 0.028846, 0.0075, 0.00051, 0.006329, 0.065789, 0.1125, 
0.003125, 0.003889, 0.000391, 0.011905, 0.004, 0, 0.00025, 0.005, 
0.076923, 0.149254, 0.0220719438793245, 0.360246999999988, 0.057692, 
0, 0.015625, 0.000714, 0, 0.001087, 0.006135, 0.003846, 0.066667, 
0.009091, 0, 0.360246999999988, 0.012821), x4 = c(3.69626899674553, 
0, 4.34824643385123, 4.22834902062364, 2.94001815500766, 3.27207378750001, 
4.61543448110941, 4.56919828334781, 4.32498170308737, 3.73719264270474, 
3.87511916546257, 1.70757017609794, 3.76499759928488, 3.7635028654676, 
4.15094055396548, 3.43949059038968, 3.70423633730879, 3.18864729599972, 
2.85186960072977, 2.37291200297011, 0, 2.69983772586725, 3.23829706787539, 
3.17695898058691, 4.32314893008404, 0, 4.64518638929519, 3.17405980772503, 
0, 2.5092025223311, 2.47856649559384, 0, 2.06818586174616, 4.08439751914115, 
3.50906804501716, 3.02160271602824, 2.71349054309394, 0, 4.6020708485543, 
2.79657433321043), x5 = c(472, 502, 506, 510, 497, 493, 515, 
542, 557, 465, 480, 369.618950156498, 518, 571, 512, 520, 464, 
578, 500, 526, 489.830047438596, 345, 664.964755505884, 546, 
505, 572, 540, 567, 473, 575, 558, 509.58218597766, 579, 616, 
561, 581, 291, 415.846613389669, 476, 442), x6 = c(374, 482, 
491, 540, 534, 493, 514, 570, 577, 485, 488, 627, 542, 529, 445, 
531, 456, 535, 381, 586, 474.392596434054, 484, 487.854513298151, 
518, 524, 582, 530, 571, 582.582737417662, 572, 592, 477, 585, 
594, 574, 609, 389, 581.722630168064, 550, 458), x7 = c(5.8e-05, 
0, 0.015551, 0.01, 0, 0, 0.0683816249999983, -0.00050051658067362, 
0.068194, 0.056615, 0, 0, 0.001097, 0, 0.0683816249999983, 0, 
0.002361, 0.000781, 0.021667, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.001154, 0.001, -0.000657947357427473, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.001479, 0.001269, 0.005333, 0.000455, 
0, 0, 0), x8 = c(14, 13, 53, 24, 8, 13, 13, 20, 17, 35, 19, 11, 
42, 15, 33, 1, 20, 6, 24, 3, 14, 3, 3, 17, 42, 8, 4, 0, 5, 4, 
10, 5, 8, 41, 31, 6, 2, 18, 7, 7), x9 = c(18, 2, 49, 19, 14, 
8, 7, 6, 7, 21, 19, 1, 34, 2, 24, 3, 30, 5, 3, 12, 9, 4, 2, 9, 
59, 15, 7, 0, 20, 1, 6, 13, 1, 64, 34, 18, 12, 0, 0, 6), x10 = c(48, 
68.8884165199473, 63, 54, 78, 80, 77.3502747403963, 74, 79, 71, 
76.7682937433346, 65.0624751538981, 63, 80, 41, 81.4257054732527, 
67, 78, 80, 73, 52.5390991618267, 60.8813703575155, 66, 72, 64, 
61.266324949851, 43.2207804060158, 80, 61.708917114202, 80, 75, 
73.3412226739437, 80, 78, 57, 78, 23, 30.321279640657, 69.1391208799255, 
60.9766796474371), x11 = c(4.62, 0.81, 1.98, 1.51, 1.51, 1.2, 
0.74, 1.2, 4.04, 2.06, 1.43, 1.51, 4.16, 0.81, 0.81, 1.82, 2.1, 
0.89, 0.73, 0.97, 20.49, 1.51, 1.51, 4.09, 1.33, 0.89, 1.59, 
1.43, 4.54, 1.51, 1.2, 1.04, 1.59, 2.57, 4.4, 1.28, 0.89, 17.94, 
1.29, 1.59), x12 = c(-3, -44.4574826440087, 1, 5, 2, 2, 39.0861520260711, 
14, 0, -6, 40.5638314058397, 22.0124501206663, 3, 12, 27, 7.55072978911628, 
5, -1, -12, 0, 14.5217398963732, -2.06782290930381, -13, 4, 1, 
39.251983622172, 0, 0, 33.2355632837177, 0, 6, 20.3416928763606, 
40.7136165846826, -2, 7, 0, 9, 0.622995283657772, -6.64967287401836, 
-3.6632790085156)), .Names = c("y", "x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", 
"x6", "x7", "x8", "x9", "x10", "x11", "x12"), row.names = c(59110L, 
266133L, 110275L, 271642L, 54361L, 54818L, 59197L, 94902L, 80531L, 
291L, 51460L, 228662L, 174960L, 27500L, 105584L, 132839L, 233895L, 
194802L, 123435L, 165332L, 318615L, 133731L, 256878L, 99780L, 
31551L, 106032L, 280841L, 130066L, 136252L, 29868L, 282962L, 
55762L, 312670L, 152593L, 50020L, 220877L, 13104L, 20888L, 319386L, 
229603L), class = "data.frame")
```

#### Code (updated):

Based on comments both here and on github/caret, I have updated the code. The non-parallel forest now works, but the parallel forests do not.

```
test$x7 <- NULL # remove low variance "dummy" variable 
                # based on comments on github (link above).

library(caret)
library(randomForest)
library(party) # conditional RF
library(kernlab)
library(parallel)
library(doParallel)

t_control <- trainControl(method= "repeatedcv", number= 10,
                          repeats= 1)
mtry_def <- floor(sqrt(ncol(test)))
t_grid <- expand.grid(mtry= c(mtry_def/2, mtry_def, 2 * mtry_def))


set.seed(14387)
## works without parallel (after removing options per @topepo):
rf1 <- train(y ~ ., data= test,
             method= "cforest", trControl= t_control,
             tuneGrid= t_grid) # remove verbose, importance, proximity

## doesn't work with parallel:
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1)
registerDoParallel(cl)
rf1 <- train(y ~ ., data= test,
             method= "cforest", trControl= t_control,
             tuneGrid= t_grid, allowParallel= TRUE) # same errors as prior to edit
rf2 <- train(y ~ ., data= test,
             method= "parRF", trControl= t_control, verbose= FALSE,
             tuneGrid= t_grid, allowParallel= TRUE, proximity= FALSE,
             importance= TRUE) # same errors as prior to edit

# moving from method= "parRF" --> method= "rf" does work:
rf3 <- train(y ~ ., data= test,
             method= "rf", trControl= t_control, verbose= FALSE,
             tuneGrid= t_grid, allowParallel= TRUE, proximity= FALSE,
             importance= TRUE)

stopCluster(cl) 

# defaults (ie-- outside caret) work
rf3a <- randomForest(y ~ ., data= test, mtry= 3, importance=TRUE)
rf3b <- cforest(y ~ ., data= test, controls= cforest_control(mtry= 3))
```

#### Sessioninfo:

```
# updated sessionInfo() -- AM running on a different computer
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
 [1] stats4    grid      parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] kernlab_0.9-22      party_1.0-23        strucchange_1.5-1   sandwich_2.3-4      zoo_1.7-12          modeltools_0.2-21  
 [7] mvtnorm_1.0-3       randomForest_4.6-10 caret_6.0-52        ggplot2_1.0.1       lattice_0.20-33     doParallel_1.0.8   
[13] iterators_1.0.7     foreach_1.4.2      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.1         compiler_3.2.2      nloptr_1.0.4        plyr_1.8.3          class_7.3-13        tools_3.2.2        
 [7] digest_0.6.8        lme4_1.1-9          nlme_3.1-122        gtable_0.1.2        mgcv_1.8-7          Matrix_1.2-2       
[13] brglm_0.5-9         SparseM_1.7         coin_1.1-0          proto_0.3-10        e1071_1.6-7         BradleyTerry2_1.0-6
[19] stringr_1.0.0       gtools_3.5.0        MatrixModels_0.4-1  nnet_7.3-11         survival_2.38-3     multcomp_1.4-1     
[25] TH.data_1.0-6       minqa_1.2.4         reshape2_1.4.1      car_2.1-0           magrittr_1.5        scales_0.3.0       
[31] codetools_0.2-14    MASS_7.3-43         splines_3.2.2       pbkrtest_0.4-2      colorspace_1.2-6    quantreg_5.19      
[37] stringi_0.5-5       munsell_0.4.2


#### original sessionInfo()
R> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
 [1] parallel  stats4    grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] doParallel_1.0.8    iterators_1.0.7     foreach_1.4.2       kernlab_0.9-22      party_1.0-23        strucchange_1.5-1  
 [7] sandwich_2.3-3      zoo_1.7-12          modeltools_0.2-21   mvtnorm_1.0-3       randomForest_4.6-10 caret_6.0-52       
[13] ggplot2_1.0.1       lattice_0.20-33    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.1         compiler_3.2.2      nloptr_1.0.4        plyr_1.8.3          class_7.3-13        tools_3.2.2        
 [7] digest_0.6.8        lme4_1.1-9          gtable_0.1.2        nlme_3.1-121        mgcv_1.8-7          Matrix_1.2-2       
[13] SparseM_1.7         brglm_0.5-9         coin_1.1-0          proto_0.3-10        e1071_1.6-7         BradleyTerry2_1.0-6
[19] stringr_1.0.0       MatrixModels_0.4-1  gtools_3.5.0        nnet_7.3-10         survival_2.38-3     multcomp_1.4-1     
[25] TH.data_1.0-6       minqa_1.2.4         car_2.1-0           reshape2_1.4.1      magrittr_1.5        scales_0.3.0       
[31] codetools_0.2-14    splines_3.2.2       MASS_7.3-43         pbkrtest_0.4-2      colorspace_1.2-6    quantreg_5.19      
[37] stringi_0.5-5       munsell_0.4.2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: Interestingly, if you change "cforest" or "parRF" to "rf" it works in parallel. Btw your error is slightly different then issue 160. Your error is related to missing values in the resampled performance measures.

Also I tested the "cforest" without running it in parallel and then it works. It looks like the parallel option causes some conflict with the building of the resampled performance measures.

Comment: @phiver Thanks! Yes, I realize that my error is different than #160. It's just the same error message.

Comment: I have updated the post to include comments here and by @topepo below.... still getting errors

Comment: Also, this (not in parallel) is working / currently running and taking forever on my full dataset: `cforest_out <- rforest_out <- list()
for (i in 1:nrow(t_grid)) {
  cforest_out[[i]] <- cforest(convert_to_paid ~ ., data= train_dat[,-3],
                              controls= cforest_control(mtry= t_grid[i,1]))
  rforest_out[[i]] <- randomForest(convert_to_paid ~ ., data= train_dat[,-3],
                              mtry= t_grid[i,1], importance= TRUE, proximity= FALSE)`
}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When I run the first `cforest` model, I can see that `"In addition: There were 31 warnings (use warnings() to see them)"`. These say that

> `unused arguments (verbose = FALSE, proximity = FALSE, importance = TRUE)`

These are arguments to the `randomForest` function and not `cforest`. Removing them removes the errors.

***Update for the update:***

This looks like confusion over the `...` and where `allowParallel` can be invoked. When running the code for `rf1`, I get these warnings:

> `unused argument (allowParallel = TRUE)`

Looking at `?train` and `?cforest`, neither has that argument; it is in `trainControl`.

Here is the confusing part: running `rf3` with `allowParallel` as an argument to `train` does *not* generate an error. This is because `cforest` does not have the ellipses and `randomForest` does:

```
> names(formals(cforest))
[1] "formula"  "data"     "subset"   "weights"  "controls" "xtrafo"  
[7] "ytrafo"   "scores"   
> names(formals(randomForest:::randomForest.default))
 [1] "x"           "y"           "xtest"       "ytest"      
 [5] "ntree"       "mtry"        "replace"     "classwt"    
 [9] "cutoff"      "strata"      "sampsize"    "nodesize"   
[13] "maxnodes"    "importance"  "localImp"    "nPerm"      
[17] "proximity"   "oob.prox"    "norm.votes"  "do.trace"   
[21] "keep.forest" "corr.bias"   "keep.inbag"  "..."
```

So, for `rf1` there is no "bottomless pit" to send the inappropriate argument (`allowParallel`) but for `rf3` there is a sequence of `...` arguments and none of the functions ever have a terminal test to see if `allowParallel` is an inappropriate argument.

***tl;dr***

Pass `allowParallel` to `trainControl` and not `train`.

Max

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. I still get the same errors. I have updated my post.

Comment: Thanks! This works... `method= "parRF"` is still problematic, but I still get parallel runs with `method="rf"`... now I am wondering if I should stop my runs w/o caret and parallel to make use of all 8 cores that I have.. hmm

Comment: In what way is it problematic? Also, consider that using `parRF` has the potential to square the number of processes that you create (`train` does things in parallel and in each worker, `parRF` does more in parallel). I think that using the sequential random forest in parallel (instead of using `parRF`) is more efficient since there is a lot less I/O and worker startups but I don't have a lot of data on that so far. That was the idea behind the `allowParallel` so that you can enable/disable it at different levels in the call stack.

Comment: as in the call to `rf2 <- ...` (above) still gives me an error but the call to `rf3 <- ...` doesn't.

Comment: ... I'm still learning the caret syntax. Your logic on I/O overhead makes sense, though I'm not sure what you mean by the implied advantage to enabling/disabling `allowParallel` at different levels of the call stack. IE-- I'm having a hard time imagining when I'd want to **not** run an embarrassingly parallel problem (ie bootstrapping) in parallel. But perhaps there are use-cases.

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be cause from multiple scenario, one the common is use allowParallel parameter at wrong place. allowParallel parameter should be inside the trainControl function which itself a parameter of train function. Check out the trainControl function docs: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-78/topics/trainControl

Comment: This was the issue for me, I accidentally put `preProcess` in `trainControl` instead of `train`. Thanks!