# R: Something is wrong; all the Accuracy metric values are missing

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret, data-science

When running `rpart`, I am getting an error message saying :

> Something is wrong; all the Accuracy metric values are missing:

The dataset can be found [here](https://github.com/Rahman96/data.combined) and has no NAs, can someone help?

```
> rf.5.cv.1
# Random Forest
# 891 samples
# 6 predictor
# 2 classes: '0', '1'
# No pre-processing
# Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 10 times) 
# Summary of sample sizes: 802, 802, 803, 801, 801, 802, ... 
# Resampling results across tuning parameters:
# mtry Accuracy Kappa 
# 2 0.8383655 0.6496840
# 4 0.8289433 0.6339793
# 6 0.8219857 0.6196764
# Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using the largest value.
# The final value used for the model was mtry = 2. 
library(rpart)
library(caret)
library(snow)
library(doSNOW)

data.combined <- read.csv("data_combined.csv")
rf.label <- as.factor(data.combined[1:891,]$Survived)
cv.10.folds <- createMultiFolds(rf.label,k = 10,times = 10)
ctrl.1 <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 10, repeats = 10,
               index = cv.10.folds)

rpart.cv <- function(seed, training, labels, ctrl) {
            set.seed(seed)
            cl <- makeCluster(6, type = "SOCK")
            registerDoSNOW(cl)
            rpart.cv <- train(x = training,
                              y = labels,
                              method = "rpart",
                              tunelength = 3, trControl = ctrl)
            stopCluster(cl)
            return(rpart.cv)
            }

features <- c("Pclass","Title", "Sex","Fare","Age","Family.Size")
rpart.train.1 <- data.combined[1:891,features]
rpart.1.cv.1 <- rpart.cv(1287, rpart.train.1, rf.label, ctrl.1)
# Something is wrong; all the Accuracy metric values are missing:
# Accuracy Kappa 
# Min. : NA Min. : NA 
# 1st Qu.: NA 1st Qu.: NA 
# Median : NA Median : NA 
# Mean :NaN Mean :NaN 
# 3rd Qu.: NA 3rd Qu.: NA 
# Max. : NA Max. : NA 
# NA's :3 NA's :3 
# Error in train.default(x = training, y = labels, method = "rpart",      
# tunelength = 3, : 
# Stopping
# In addition: Warning message:
# In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo, :
# There were missing values in resampled performance measures.
# Called from: train.default(x = training, y = labels, method = "rpart",     
# tunelength = 3, 
# trControl = ctrl)
# Browse[1]> Q
# >
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting this error in Caret](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30475723/getting-this-error-in-caret)

Comment: @phiver, the suggestions made in those answers do not help in this case.

Comment: so, what now ? :\

Comment: I checked your function. There is a mistake in there. tuneLength should be with a capital L. Fix that and it should work.

Comment: @phiver , it worked ! , thank you i didn't notice that